# Positioning a node with respect to a group of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I have a set of nodes that is generated by a macro, and I would like to position a node with respect to the north, west, south of this set of nodes. In my example I would for instance like to position the node labelled by `(A)` at the west of the group of nodes generated by the macro `\graphcircuit` and the problem is that I neither know the size of the generated figure (i.e., it depends of the list that is passed to the macro), nor have some kind of global node I could refer at.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand{\graphcircuit}[1]{
\foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{90/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
\foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n] \v in {#1}
  \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n-\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}
  \draw[semithick,-stealth] (n-\j) to[bend right=\b] (n-\i);
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1}
    \node[font=\normalsize] (A) at (0,0) {(A)}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Your code" is the code from my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219364/9335. 
I think that you have to : 1) cite your source, 2) post an image of the result, and if possible of what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fit the whole graph into a node and refer to it. And you don't need the `math` library for this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\newcommand{\graphcircuit}[1]{
\begin{scope}
\def\myfitarray{}
\foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{90/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
\foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n] \v in {#1}
  \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n-\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}{
  \draw[semithick,-stealth] (n-\j) to[bend right=\b] (n-\i);}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{%
\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\myfitarray\expandafter{\myfitarray (n-\x)}}
\node[inner sep=2pt,fit=\myfitarray] (groupnode) {};
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1}
    \node[font=\normalsize,anchor=south] (A) at (groupnode.north) {(A)}; 
    \node[font=\normalsize,anchor=east] (B) at (groupnode.west) {(B)}; 
    \begin{scope}[shift={(4,5)}]% Another one
        \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1}
    \node[anchor=north] (C) at (groupnode.south) {(C)}; 
    \node[anchor=north west] (D) at (groupnode.south east) {(D)}; 
    \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mea culpa for `math` library. It was forgotten in my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219364/9335 from the first version. I just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the OP's code, the first node can be used as the global reference point. Here the label (A) located 1 cm (which is defined by `\s`macro) to the right of the first node is used for the global reference for the group of nodes. Once this is set, one can use `above, below, right, left= xx cm of A` and its variants to locate the remaining nodes. However, `north, west, south` is preferred in this example, the solution uses `polar coordinate` to place the remaining nodes.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\graphcircuit}[1]{
\foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{90/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
\foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n] \v in {#1}
  \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n-\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}
  \draw[semithick,-stealth] (n-\j) to[bend right=\b] (n-\i);
}
  \def\s{1}      % determine the location of the global reference
  \begin{document}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1}  
  \node[font=\normalsize,xshift=\s cm] (A) at (n-1) {(A)}; 
  \node[font=\normalsize] (B) at (180:\r+\s) {(B)}; 
  \node[font=\normalsize] (C) at (90:\r+\s)  {(C)}; 
  \node[font=\normalsize] (D) at (-90:\r+\s) {(D)}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1,1:1,2:2,3:3}

  \node[font=\normalsize,xshift=\s cm] (A) at (n-1) {(A)}; 
  \node[font=\normalsize] (B) at (180:\r+\s) {(B)}; 
  \node[font=\normalsize] (C) at (90:\r+\s)  {(C)}; 
  \node[font=\normalsize] (D) at (-90:\r+\s) {(D)}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1,1:1,2:2,3:3,1:1,2:2,3:3}

 \node[font=\normalsize,xshift=\s cm] (A) at (n-1) {(A)}; 
 \node[font=\normalsize] (B) at (180:\r+\s) {(B)}; 
 \node[font=\normalsize] (C) at (90:\r+\s)  {(C)}; 
 \node[font=\normalsize] (D) at (-90:\r+\s) {(D)}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 2:** Here is another solution using `local bounding box`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\graphcircuit}[2]{
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=#2]
  \foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{90/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
  \foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n] \v in {#1}
    \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n-\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}
    \draw[semithick,-stealth] (n-\j) to[bend right=\b] (n-\i);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1}{groupnode}
    \foreach \a in {north, east, south, west}
      \node[circle, fill=red, inner sep=1pt] at (groupnode.\a) [label={\a:\a}]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SOLUTION 1:**
Here is a solution without `fit` library, that draw the graph inside a node. Personally I prefer the `fit` solution of percusse and my second solution. I give this one for the sake of completeness.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\graphcircuit}[2]{
\node[name=#2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[count=\n] \v in {#1}; % count the number of elements
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\n*0.2} % set the node distance from (0,0)
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{90/\n} % evaluate the bend angle
  \foreach[count=\i, evaluate=\i as \a using (\i-1)*360/\n] \v in {#1}
    \node [circle, draw, font=\scriptsize] (n-\i) at (\a:\r) {$\v$};
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially \n)] in {1,...,\n}
    \draw[semithick,-stealth] (n-\j) to[bend right=\b] (n-\i);
  \end{tikzpicture}
};}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graphcircuit{1:5,7:2,3:0,4:0,9:1}{groupnode}
    \foreach \a in {north, east, south, west}
      \node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt] at (groupnode.\a) [label={\a:\a}]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]